# how to know whether Formit Validation is successful or not in a snippet

Tags: php, validation, modx-revolution, formit

I am using FormIt validation in my modx chunk. How do I know whether FormIt validation is successful or not? I mean how can I use in my code the validation result? Is something like this possible:

```
if (formit_validation=="success") 
//do some code
else
//do some code
```

?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get errors in chunk, then use `[[!+fi.validation_error_message]]` placeholder ( http://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/formit ). In snippet is more hard, just provide your snippet in "hooks", he will be called after the form is validated.